# Can be "due to" used with regards to a 'positive' consequence attributable to a person?

Tags: usage, objects

I am not sure of whether this use of "due to" is correct or not:

> *"This progress is due to Thomas."*

Where it says *"progress"* you can put any sort of *positive* result, tool or contribution, such as *"solution"*, *"method"*, etc. Instead of *"Thomas"*, consider any other *person*.

So, my question is: **Does it make sense to use *"due to"* when referring to something *good* or *positive* that can be attributed to someone? If not, what are some ways to express this in a more natural English?**

This doubt arises because I frequently see *"due to"* used as associated to negative consequences caused by something which is not a person. For instance: *"The delay is due to an engine malfunction"*.

Comment: Yes, this usage is common in academic writing. It is used like a citation to give credit for something mentioned in the text to the appropriate person or group. Think of it as similar to "we have this (result / method / whatever) **thanks** to..." Surprisingly, I haven't been able to find this usage in any of the online dictionaries I checked, or other references to cite, which is why this is a comment instead of an answer. If I find something I will post an answer. Otherwise you will have to take my word for it ;-)

Comment: @TypeIA Thank you! That was my problem: Though the expression sounded familiar to me, I was not able to find any proper example. My context is academic writing, by the way.